# Reading a hexadecimal value from a string into a decimal long

Tags: c, hex, type-conversion

I have a string which contains a hexadecimal value:

```
"29E94B25"
```

I want to convert this hexadecimal string into an unsigned long using a base of 10. e.g. I want to create an unsigned long with a value of:

```
703154981
```

How can I do this type conversion?

Comment: 5*10^0 + 2*10^1 + 11*10^2 + ... + 2*10^7

Comment: @scibuff I was looking for a method that I could call to do it for me. Along the lines of atol().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read this string into an unsigned long with `strtoul`:

```
unsigned long n = strtoul("29E94B25", NULL, 16);
```

You can then print it in base-10 with `printf`.

There's no such thing as an `unsigned long` with a base other than 2.

Comment: What do you mean by "no such thing as unsigned long in a base other than 2". Why is it so ?

Comment: All C integer types store binary numbers. They can be printed in decimal, hex, whatever, but that always requires a conversion.

Answer (score 2):

`strtoul` is what you need

```
unsigned long x;
x = strtoul("29E94B25", 0, 16);
```

Answer (score 1):

One could use `sscanf` for any type converstions.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    main(){
      char a[] = "29E94B25";
      unsigned long int b;
      sscanf(a,"%X",&b);
      printf("%ld",b);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### C#

```
String hexNumber = "000001ae";
int i = Int32.Parse(hexNumber, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
MessageBox.Show(i); (or Console.Write(i))
```

### C:

```
int main(void)
{
char s[] = "0D76";
unsigned long x;
x = strtoul(s, 0, 16);
printf("The value represented by the string \"%s\" is\n"
"%lu (decimal)\n" "%#lo (octal)\n" "%#lx (hex)\n",
s, x, x, x);
return 0;
}
```